# kendo grid server re filtering the data source

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var agenciesData = new kendo.DataToken.DataSource({
        type: 'webapi',
        transport: {
            read: { url: "/api/Agencies/", dataType: "json", data: { activity: getActivity() } },
            create: { url: "/api/Agencies", type: "POST", dataType: "json" },
            destroy: { url: "/api/Agencies/{0}", type: "DELETE" },
            update: { url: "/api/Agencies/{0}", type: "PUT" },
            idField: "ID"
        },
        filter: [{ field: "Activity", operator: "eq", value: getActivity() }],
        pageSize: 15,
        page: 1,
        total: 0,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        schema: {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total",
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    ID: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                    AgencyName: { type: "string" },
                    AgentName: { type: "string" },
                    Address: { type: "string" },
                    City: { type: "string" },
                    Tel1: { type: "string" },
                    Tel2: { type: "string" },
                    Pele: { type: "string" },
                    Activity: { type: "number" },
                    ToDate: { type: "date" }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#agenciesGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: agenciesData,
        toolbar: [{ text: "valid", className: "validAgents" }, { text: "not valid", className: "notValid" }, { text: "all", className: "allAgents" }, { text: "potential", className: "potetial" }],
        editable: false,
        navigatable: true,
        sortable: true,
        autoBind: false,
        height: 430,
        pageable: { refresh: true },
        columns: [
            { field: "ID", hidden: true },
            { field: "AgencyName", title: "agency", width: 150, filterable: { cell: { operator: "contains" } } },
            { field: "AgentName", title: "agent", width: 150, filterable: { cell: { operator: "contains" } } },
            { field: "Address", title: "address", width: 200, template: "#= Address + ' ' + City #", filterable: false },
            { field: "Tel1", title: "phones", width: 300, template: "#= Tel1 + ' : ' + Tel2 + ' : ' + Pele #", filterable: false },
            { field: "Activity", title: "active", width: "90px" },
            { field: "ToDate", title: "end Contract", type: "date", width: 90, format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"] }
        ]
    });


    $(".validAgents").click(function () { //valid
        $("#myActivity").val("1");
        $('#agenciesGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.read({ activity: "1" });
    });

    $(".notValid").click(function () {//notValid
        $("#myActivity").val("2");
        $('#agenciesGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.read({ activity: "2" });
    });

    $(".potetial").click(function () {//potetial
        $("#myActivity").val("3");
        $('#agenciesGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.read({ activity: "3" });
    });
});


function getActivity(){
    var myActivity = $("#myActivity").val();
    return myActivity;
}
```

When I use kendo grid already filtered by parameter like : $('#someGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.read({ activity: value });
i see the get: **https://localhost:44305/api/Agencies/?sort=&page=1&pageSize=15&group=&filter=&activity=1**

The grid is filter as expected but, when I want to do paging, sorting, refresh - I get the whole data ignoring the filter that i made.
and I see the get: **https://localhost:44305/api/Agencies/?sort=&page=1&pageSize=15&group=&filter=**

How can I save my filter state to do paging and sorting on the data came from the server side ?
even when i used differen approach like "scrollable: { virtual: true }" and when i scroll down - every request is without the filtering...

Thanks

Comment: try using the `dataSource.filter(filter)` method instead of putting the filter in `.read(filter)`. If `{activity:value}` is not a filter, but additional data to be passed to the server, try putting it in `transport.read.data` instead

Comment: how can i paging on the filtered data without destroy the data set ?

Comment: Did you mean to use client side paging and sorting? That way it won't call the server again when you want to page and sort.

Comment: I did the "filter: [{ field: "Activity", operator: "eq", value: "1" }]" and now i see the paging reqests are like: https://localhost:44305/api/Agencies/?sort=&page=2&pageSize=15&group=&filter=Activity~eq~%271%27.              i think i missed something becuase i get "405 Method Not Allowed" when data load i see "https://localhost:44305/api/Agencies/?sort=&page=1&pageSize=15&group=&filter=Activity~eq~%271%27&activity=1" should i need to use also the read filter param ?

Comment: yeah it looks like you want {activity:1} to be additional data sent to the server, so try the `transport.read.data` param

Comment: ok, success ont the first step: now i reqest this on load the data to the grid: https://localhost:44305/api/Agencies/?sort=&page=1&pageSize=15&group=&filter=Activity~eq~%271%27&activity=1 but when i do paging i see the reqest: https://localhost:44305/api/Agencies/?sort=&page=2&pageSize=15&group=&filter=Activity~eq~%271%27&activity=2 why the activity changed to 2 ?

Comment: What did you set `transport.read.data` to?

Comment: read: { url: "/api/Agencies/", dataType: "json", data: { activity: getActivity() } }

Comment: Only reason I would imagine activity changed to 2 is because you clicked `.notValid`. Every new call to the server will check for the activity value. Did you click it?

Comment: on the first step i click on "validAgents" on the grid bar to get the active agents from the server and then i paging to next page 2

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, try replacing data with a function like `data:function(){return{ activity: getActivity() };}`

Comment: what i figure out is the function getActivity() call once when the grid load and then, when i change the activity value the filter send the old parameter and that is the reason for the confusion... so, how can i set this up ?

Comment: have you tried what I said right above you, giving data a function?

Comment: Yes I did, it's fire once when the grid data load, I need to do something to enforce the fetch grid data source to get the new value as filter data. for instance, when i click on "valid" - I can paging and sorting and it's ok. but, when I click on "not valid" i want the grid to fech the new data value which is not fire

Comment: when click on "Valid" the get: /api/Agencies/?0=1&sort=&page=1&pageSize=15&group=&filter=activity~eq~%271%27&activity=1  And when I click on "Not Valid" the get: /api/Agencies/?0=1&sort=&page=4&pageSize=15&group=&filter=activity~eq~%271%27&activity=2

Comment: the: filter=activity~eq~%271%27 stays always the same value...

Comment: Okay so from what I understand, the activity=value is working, but filter is not updating properly. Try making filter a function as well? `filter: function(){return [{ field: "Activity", operator: "eq", value: getActivity() }];}`

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a codepen.io for me to mess around with.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
var agenciesData = new kendo.DataToken.DataSource({
  filter : function () {
     return object;
  }
});
```

I mean try using filter as a function and you can do your logic inside the function depending on the situation.

Comment: now with your advice - i did this:  filter : function() {
            var ds = $("#agenciesGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
            ds.filter([{ "filters": [{ "field": "Activity", "operator": "eq", "value": getActivity() }] }]);
        } and reqest link look like that: /api/Agencies/?sort=&page=1&pageSize=15&group=&filter=&activity=1 which is not filter at all

Comment: will i need (on the server) to cancel the activiy parameter ?

Comment: with this filter there is poor performance because in the server get from all list and return the filter...